# GroupBy does not seem to group by DateTime but rather just by Date

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var items = new List<CustomItem> 
{
    new CustomItem()
    {
        Id = 90, // int
        ParentId = 10, // int
        CreateDate = '1/19/2020 1:04 PM' // DateTime
    },
    new CustomItem() 
    {
        Id = 91,
        ParentId = 10,
        CreateDate = '1/19/2020 1:04 PM'
    },
    new CustomItem()
    {
        Id = 92,
        ParentId = 10,
        CreateDate = '1/19/2020 2:32 PM'
    }
};
```

Now what I would like to do is `GroupBy` the `CreateDate` and then `OrderBy` and select the first of each group.

So, I have the following code and I would expect to only have the items with Ids of 90 and 91 but I am getting all three. It's almost as if the `GroupBy` is only grouping by the date and not by the time as well. Is this how it works or am I missing something?

Current code:

```
var newItems = items.Where(item => item.ParentId == 10).GroupBy(item => item.CreateDate).Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate).First())
```

Comment: This is not a C# array, and adds extra work for us to test. Consider adding an [mcve]

Comment: @00110001 Sorry, I was just trying to make the question easier to understand but I realize that probably just made it more confusing. I'll go edit the post now to make it more clear.

Comment: In each group, the members have the same `CreateDate`, but then you go on to `OrderBy` this `CreateDate` within the group? That seems wrong. (Not an answer to your question.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's probably just the result of me trying to see what would work. Even if I don't `OrderBy` within the group, I still get a group with all 3 items even though the `DateTime`s don't exactly match

Comment: `select the first of each group` based on this logic and the data you shared the outcome should be 90 and 92. Isn't it?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BUNlhR  is this not working the way you want?

Comment: What's the declaration of `CustomItem`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya You are correct. Thanks for pointing that out because I totally missed that. I do not just want the first, I want everything in that group. But it seems like I am still getting all 3 items in a group instead of just 90 & 91 in one group and 92 in another group.

Comment: Did you check the actual values of CreateDate you are getting from database? Did you check if they are same even at seconds level.

Comment: If this is coming from a DB, the DateTime should not be string :/

Comment: Help me understand, you are getting only one group and NOT three groups, is that right?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Lol that's the issue. I was thinking I was looking at one group with 3 items in it. I was looking at 3 separate groups though. /facepalm. Thanks for all of the help everyone and sorry for any wasted time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple different `DateTime` values whose string representations (in some culture) are `"1/19/2020 1:04 PM"`. The precision of a `DateTime` is 100 nanoseconds. If two `DateTime` differ by, say, one microsecond, they may look like they are equal to you, but they will still end up in different groups (since they are not *exactly* equal).

Besides, from your description, it sounds like you want to order the groups, not the members of each group, so:

```
items.Where(item => item.ParentId == 10)
  .GroupBy(item => item.CreateDate)
  .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
  .First()
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on grouping by `DateTime` and explaining the precision. Those are things I never knew. And thanks also for your answer, because, yes, that is exactly what I was wanting. I was just going about it the wrong way and didn't fully understand my own logic lol.